# cannot initialize type with a collection initializer because it does not implement ienumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I'm a fairly junior C# developer so please excuse me if this is very easy, but I am getting this error "`invalid initializer member declarator`" at this line of the code below:

```
foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
{
  DBTrack top = new DBTrack()
 /* ===> Error starts here */   {
     track.TrackID = SQLDataHelper.GetGuid(dataReader, "TrackID"); 
     track.TrackName = SQLDataHelper.GetString(dataReader, "TrackName");
     track.ArtistName = SQLDataHelper.GetString(dataReader, "ArtistName");
     track.AddedDate = SQLDataHelper.GetDateTime(dataReader, "AddedDate");
    };

 DBTrackData.Add(top);
}
```

Can someone explain what this means and how do I work around and achieve it to display the data?

Here's the full method for your inspection:

```
 public static List<DBTrack> GetAllTracksFromReaderDB(IDataReader dataReader)
 {
  if (DBTrackData == null)
  {
     DBTrack track = new DBTrack();
     System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
     List<DBTrack> daa = new List<DBTrack>();
     DBTrackData = new List<DBTrack>();

     foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
     {

     DBTrack top = new DBTrack()
     /* ===> Error starts here */   {
     track.TrackID = SQLDataHelper.GetGuid(dataReader, "TrackID"); 
     track.TrackName = SQLDataHelper.GetString(dataReader, "TrackName");
     track.ArtistName = SQLDataHelper.GetString(dataReader, "ArtistName");
     track.AddedDate = SQLDataHelper.GetDateTime(dataReader, "AddedDate");
     };

    DBTrackData.Add(top);

    }
  }
  return DBTrackData;

 }
```

**EDIT:**

```
public Guid TrackID { get; set; }
public string TrackName { get; set; }
public string ArtistName { get; set; }
public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
```

Any help would be great :) Thanks

Comment: How is DBTrack defined?

Comment: thanks - it's defined as `public`

Comment: No, not the access modifier, how is the class defined? show us the class so we can see its properties.

Comment: thanks - would this help? `public static List<DBTrack> DBTrackData = null;` sorry if I misunderstood it :)

Comment: have you defined as { Guid, string ,string, Datetime}???

Comment: change semicolons to just commas `;` => `,`

Comment: @mehow thanks - I tried that initially before asking here, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: +1 because he is a gentle OP...

Comment: @apomene ahaha - thanks for that! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid for member initialization. You cant instansiate `top` and try to fill `track` properties.

It should look like this:

```
DBTrack top = new DBTrack
{
   TrackID = SQLDataHelper.GetGuid(dataReader, "TrackID"),
   TrackName = SQLDataHelper.GetString(dataReader, "TrackName"),
   ArtistName = SQLDataHelper.GetString(dataReader, "ArtistName"),
   AddedDate = SQLDataHelper.GetDateTime(dataReader, "AddedDate")
};
```

Comment: thanks for that, it resolved my issue. :) I minor question, how can I amend your code without the `dataReader` parameter.. is it possible to do so? thanks again for your help it's working :)

Comment: You mean how you can copy it without the dataReader parameter? just copy it normally and delete the parameter

Comment: thanks - I tried that initially, but I get the following error `no overload for method takes 1 argument` i.e. `TrackID = NSMSQLDataHelper.GetGuid("TrackID"),`.. only if it's possible. If not then it's ok ;) thanks again for your help

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean now. Well, you cant drop the argument if the `GetGuid` method needs to accept it as a parameter.

Comment: ahh I c what you mean! - thanks for that and for all your help :)